# Ajax call to code behind. Reaching complete stage, but not returning success or triggering code behind function

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax, vb.net

I'm attempting to trigger a code behind method from AJAX:

```
function onEnter(key) {
  var lotTxt = document.getElementById("lotTxt");
  if (key.keyCode == 13) {
    alert("in if")
    $.ajax({
      url: 'Default.aspx/assEatinSzn',
      type: "POST",
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      data: { test: "testString"},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        alert("Success")
      },
      failure: function (data) {
        alert("Failure")
      }
    });
  }
}
```

All I am attempting to do in the code behind is update this text box with the value below:

```
Public Sub assEatinSzn(test As String)
  productTxt.Value = "Success"
End Sub
```

Essentially I am asking why the ajax is not triggering the code behind method. I have put break points to see if the the code behind method is ever triggered, but nothing ever breaks. The ajax method will produce the complete function as well in a weird side effect. Thanks in advance

Comment: and what is the question ?

Comment: instead of adding it as a comment, explain your issue in your post and i'll try to post an answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are not passing a value for the `test` parameter.Hope the below code will solve your issue :

```
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'default.aspx/assEatinSzn',
  data: JSON.stringify({ test: 'value here' }),
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
  }
  ......
```

And make sure to add `[WebMethod]` before your method :

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
 Public Shared Sub assEatinSzn(test As String)
 productTxt.Value = "Success"
 End Sub
```

Comment: After I made this change I am still only getting the alerts("In if") and ("Complete"). The break point of the code behind is never being reached.

Comment: @lildakota are you sure your entire AJAX function is being executed ?

Comment: Honestly no. This is my first attempt at writing an ajax method. I attempted to place break points in the ajax method but it seems that either the URL is returning false and breaking me out of the ajax method. I did at one point place alerts within the method, and those were being executed.

Comment: I have updated my code above to reflect the changes you suggested, but am still not accessing my server side code. Not sure what the issue is, but thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you include `[WebMethod]` above your method ?

Comment: Trying to right now, but it is asking for declaration. Not sure if this is viable in Vb.net

Comment: No, it's not a variable,it's an attribute, make sure you add reference to `System.Web.Services` in order to add `[WebMethod]`

Comment: In my reference manager I have the reference to System.Web.Services. Then I attempted to declare [WebMethod], but I am still getting the error.  Hopefully the issue is not because I do not have reference to PageMethods or scriptmanager. Thank you again for all of your help.

Comment: @lildakota , you need to add the reference from your code too : `Imports System.Web.Services`

Comment: It is there, sorry for the miscommunication. Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Script.Services